# Workaround for inheriting from sealed derived class?

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance

I want to derive from a derived class `SealedDerived` but I can't because the class is `sealed`. If I instead derive from the base class `Base`, is there any way I can "cheat" and redirect the `this` reference to an object of the `SealedDerived` class?

For example, like this:

```
public class Base { ... }

public sealed class SealedDerived : Base { ... }

public class MyDerivedClass : Base
{
    public MyDerivedClass()
    {
        this = new SealedDerived();  // Won't work, but is there another way?
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT** Upon request, here is the context: I am porting a .NET class library that makes extensive use of `System.Drawing.Bitmap` to a *Windows Store* library. My primary idea to workaround the lack of the `System.Drawing.Bitmap` class in *Windows Store* was to implement a dummy `Bitmap` class that would inherit from `WriteableBitmap` and thereby be able to return a bitmap object of the *Windows Store* kind. Unfortunately `WriteableBitmap` is `sealed`. Its base class `BitmapSource` is (of course) not sealed, but on the other hand provides practically no methods for manipulating the image. Hence my dilemma.

Something like this:

```
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging;

namespace System.Drawing {
  public class Bitmap : BitmapSource {
    public Bitmap(int width, int height) {
      this = new WriteableBitmap(width, height);  // Will not work...
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

Ideally, I want my fake `Bitmap` to represent a bitmap type of the *Windows Store* kind, so that I for example can assign my fake `Bitmap` class to an `Image.Source`.

Comment: No, that won't work. You could possibly use composition instead, but we can't really tell. Why don't you tell us the bigger problem you're trying to solve, and we may be able to help more.

Comment: What John said. Also, depending on what you're trying to accomplish, extension methods may be an option.

Comment: inheritance  I  don't  think  will be the right choice  here as jon saied  try  to explain more  and perhaps we will provide you  with the  correct design pattern  for instance try  to take  a look at http://dofactory.com/Framework/Framework.aspx

Comment: no useful comments perhaps :)

Comment: Thanks, @JonSkeet and others for taking the time to respond. I have updated the question with some background context.

Comment: How will providing a WriteableBitmap help, if the library uses System.Drawing.Bitmaps ?

Comment: @zmbq Sorry, I was not clear enough; I am porting the source code of the class library to a *Windows Store* class library.

Comment: Is it worthwhile finding a solution to that pattern, instead considering an already stable package? http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/

Comment: @MarioVernari The library I am trying to port provides various kinds of analysis and processing of the `Bitmap` images. *WriteableBitmapEx* only provides the basic initializing/drawing/filling operations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Added as an answer so I could provided the code sample but feel free to take as a comment. If you feel you must keep to this pattern an implicit type cast may help you. Without knowing what your image library is doing this just pushes the problem deeper as any `Graphics.FromImage` was never going to work regardless of approach. If your library is restricted to `GetPixel`, `SetPixel` and `LockBits` you may be able to make this work with enough effort.

```
public class Bitmap
{
    public static implicit operator WriteableBitmap(Bitmap bitmap)
    {
        return bitmap._internalBitmap;
    }

    private readonly WriteableBitmap _internalBitmap;

    public Bitmap(int width, int height)
    {
        _internalBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(width, height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Bgra32, null);
    }
}

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public Image XamlImage { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        var bitmap = new Bitmap(100, 100);
        XamlImage.Source = bitmap;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, David! I was actually beginning to experiment with the same approach as you have have described above. I am aware of that the inner workings will pose new challenges, but I'll take it one step at a time :-) I will test this and if it works I will gladly accept the answer.